# How to retrieve hyperledger success payload via nodejs client

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Given an implemented chaincode stub invoke function:

```
func (lc *chaincode) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
        return shim.Success([]byte("{\"car\":\"audi\"}"))
    }
}
```

**How does one receive the `shim.Success` payload via NodeJS?**

Upon reviewing the results after running transaction proposal: 

`channel.sendTransactionProposal(proposalRequest).then((results) => {
  console.log(results); // very complex undocumented object
});`

*The [documentation](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/) is lacking and the [sample scenarios](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/fabcar/invoke.js) are a bit too complex, therefore I thought it would be useful to have a simple answer on SO*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `channel.sendTransactionProposal` to ledger actually generates a [Response](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/global.html#Response) object which can be accessed as described below:

`results[0][0].response.payload.toString('utf-8');`